# Disabling/Enabling tabs not working jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I have a script that has next and previous buttons on a tabs in html, so when I click next it goes to another tab, the previous button is disabled when is on the first tab, and the next button is disabled when is on the last tab. Here is my html:

```
        <div class="tabbable">

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tab_bar">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Step 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Step 2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content" >
    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="content">
          Some text enter code here here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
      Some text here
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn" id="prevtab" type="button">Back</button>
  <button class="btn" id="nexttab" type="button">Next</button>
</div>
```

And here is my script so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $tabs = $('.tabbable li');

$('#prevtab').attr("disabled", true);

$('#prevtab').on('click', function () {

    if ($tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').length == 1) {
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    }
    $tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
    $('#nexttab').prop("disabled", false);
});

$('#nexttab').on('click', function () {
    if ($tabs.filter('.active').next('li').length == 1) {
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    }
    $tabs.filter('.active').next('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
    $('#prevtab').prop("disabled", false);
});
```

});

So what I want to do is to be disabled the second Tab in the start, and when I click "NEXT" the tab to be enabled. I tried with $( ".tabs" ).tabs( "disable" ); but with no success. Any idea how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the below link .He is hiding the button if there is no more tab to navigate either next/previous.So you can use the same and disable theb button instead of hiding.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-UI-Tabs-Navigation-using-Next-Previous-Buttons.aspx

and the demo of that

http://aspsnippets.com/demos/398/